# FactoryGirl is making weird emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

I have a factory set up like so:

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do

factory :user do |u|
u.sequence(:name) { |n| "User #{n}"}
u.sequence(:email) { |n| "user#{n}@example.com"}
u.password "password"
end

factory :student_group do |student_group|
  sequence(:name) {|n| "class #{n}"}
end


end
```

And a rake task to populate my database:

```
require 'factory_girl_rails'

namespace :db do

desc "Fill db with sample data"

task :populate, :environment do

# reset the database
puts "Resetting the database"
Rake::Task['db:reset'].invoke

# create 100 users
puts "Creating users"
new_users = FactoryGirl.create_list :user, 100

#create 3 student_groups for each user  
puts "Creating student groups for each user"
new_users.each do |u|
  FactoryGirl.create_list :student_group, 3, :user_id => u.id
end

# success message
puts "The database has been populated successfully"
end
end
```

It runs okay, but all the email fields are populated with this: `---
- user3@example.com
- User 3`

It was just working - I'm not sure what's changed, and actually I copied and pasted things back from my github repository (which makes me think the error is elsewhere) - what could be causing the email to be formed like this?  if you need more files, just ask, i'm quite confused as to what could be the trouble.

**EDIT** to make sure the error is not from something left over in the database, i did rake db:reset and checked the db table again...it was empty, so it's not that!  still looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output looks like a hash. You don't need argument `u` in the defining block according to latest FactoryGirl - maybe your old repo used old syntax.

It should look like this:

```
factory :user do
  sequence(:name) { |n| "User #{n}"}
  sequence(:email) { |n| "user#{n}@example.com"}
  password "password"
end
```

Comment: thanks, that's a good fix anyway, but still getting the same output: `---
- user1@example.com
- User 1`

Comment: @dax, when you mentioned the format, is it the format you saw in db field, or is it something printed on browser? If the later it would be problem of view.

Comment: got it!  there was an error in a before_save filter in my user.rb that was messing up the email.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: oh, that's something in farm but not factory.